# How to optimize getYoutubeViews function so as not to exceed the daily Youtube API quota?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube

I am trying to automate the collection of statistics on Youtube videos in google spreadsheets. To do this, I use code in spreadsheets script editor with the getYoutubeViews function, as well as with the GETURL, linkURL functions, and so on.

Here is the getYoutubeViews function sample

```
function getYoutubeViews(videoId){
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=" + videoId;
  url = url + "&key=mykey";
  //Utilities.sleep(Math.random(15000))
  var videoListResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = JSON.parse(videoListResponse.getContentText());
  return json["items"][0]["statistics"]["viewCount"];
}

function GETURL(input) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input);
  var url = /"(.*?)"/.exec(range.getFormulaR1C1())[1];
  return url;
}
```

I ran into two problems.

The script starts working when the user loads the table. This starts a large number of processes, since the number of videos in the table exceeds 600 pieces. This causes the error: "Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps".

But fixing it with Utilities.sleep does not make sense, because there is a second problem. Google’s API key quota of 10,000 points ends after 3-4 hours of work and regular table reloads.

I tried to minimize functions and actions on list, and use Utilities.sleep, to avoid this error:

```
Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. 
Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. (строка 0).
```

But it seems that this does not help to solve the quota problem.

It seems to me that I can somehow save data in cells, activating functions only when updating data. I tried to use change triggers for these purposes, but either I did it wrong or it didn't help.

The second assumption is that it would be possible to somehow save the previous data, so that there would be some data in the cells even in case of a script error. But I do not know how this can be done.

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue is that one `viewCount` value is retrieved using one video ID. If in your current situation, you run the function of `getYoutubeViews()` by the custom function, for example, how about running one script with the OnOpen event trigger? In this case, several `viewCount` values can be retrieved by one API call. By this, I think that the consumption of quota will be reduced.

Answer (score 2):

An approach to avoid using custom functions (which will make all requests each time), is to use an onOpen() trigger to add a menu [1] that when clicked runs the getYoutubeViews() function. This function will make the request and insert the response data (views count) in the spreadsheet. It'll take the videoIds from B column (starting from 2nd row) and set the views count in D column. I put an "If" condition so that only makes the request (an update the values) for the empty views cells.

To manipulate the data on the spreadsheet I used SpreadsheetApp class [2]

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Actions')
  .addItem('Add views', 'getYoutubeViews')
  .addToUi();  
}

function getYoutubeViews(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
  var videoIdArray = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var views = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);

  for(var i=0; i<videoIdArray.length ; i++) {
    var videoId = videoIdArray[i][0];
    var viewsCell = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 4);

    if(viewsCell.getValue() == "") {
      var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=" + videoId;
      url = url + "&key=AAIzaSyAUjC5AchndLg9BRIrRBYKLuKf-fFkMC9M";
      var options = {
        'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
        'headers': {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
        }
      };

      var videoListResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var json = JSON.parse(videoListResponse.getContentText());
      Logger.log(json)

      var views = json["items"][0]["statistics"]["viewCount"];
      viewsCell.setValue(views);
    }
  }
}
```

You can not run the code directly with the onEdit() function because triggers have restrictions [3], among which there's one that says:

> They cannot access services that require authorization.

UrlFetchApp.fetch() is a service that requires authorization from the user.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions